# How do I disable the dialog/popup that appears after firefox is upgraded?

Tags: firefox

I'm using a dedicated firefox profile, a custom `user.js` file, and a custom `userChrome.css` file to get firefox to mimic chrome's --app flag. However one problem I found during my testing is that firefox presents a dialog whenever firefox is updated to a new version. How do I stop this dialog from appearing?

Here's a screenshot that shows the dialog in question:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Firefox 108.0.x, the way to do this is to set `browser.startup.upgradeDialog.enabled` to false inside your user.js file or by setting it manually in about:config:

```js
user_pref("browser.startup.upgradeDialog.enabled", false);
```

This approach was tested and is confirmed to work with Firefox 108.0.1 when upgrading from Firefox 102.x.x (tested on 2022-12-21).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).